# Django tastypie nested toManyField pagination

Tags: python, django, tastypie

I have this tastypie resource:

```
class BlogPostResource(ModelResource):
    comments = fields.ToManyField('comments.api.CommentResource', 'comments', full=True)
```

The blog endpoint `/api/v1/blog/13` gives back the following response:

```
{
  id: 13,
  text: 'blog example',
  comments: [{id: 1, comment: "1"},{id: 2, comment: "2"}, ...]
}
```

I was expecting comments to be paginated like this:

```
{
  id: 13,
  text: 'blog example',
  comments:{
    meta: {
      limit: 20,
      next: "/api/v1/comment/?offset=20&limit=20&format=json", 
      offset: 0,
      previous: null,
      total_count: 36
    },
    objects: [{id: 1, comment: "1"},{id: 2, comment: "2"}, ...]
  }
}
```

How can I make comments paginated to get the response I was expecting?

Comment: I tried add `filtering = {'blog': ALL}` to comment's `Meta class`, then query comments with `note=n`, got the similar structure you want.

Comment: I am not sure how to query using note=n. Can you elaborate a little more? Thanks

Comment: https://gist.github.com/4432602